# Solr Search & Pagination

Tags: magento-enterprise, catalogsearch, search, solr

Is there a step needed to get Pagination to work when Solr Search is enabled?

**Some background on our where we are:**

We have Solr Search enabled and dialed in `solrconfig.xml`.  The results look good but we just noticed the Pagination isn't working? Do we have to pass different parameters so Solr?

Comment: Pagination is not a problem of solr. What magento version do you use? Do you have extensions which extends catalog functionality?

Comment: You're absolutely correct oleksii. Disabling and then fixing the functionality that extended the toolbar.php class fixed everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\catalogsearch.xml` if is defined toolbar pager and it is used.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result" template="catalogsearch/result.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
        </block>
        .....
    </block>
</reference>
```

If yes check template `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml` maybe it was changed or some extension rewrites it.

Comment: Thanks Oleskii for elaborating on your comment and turning it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Oleskii stated, "Pagination is not a problem of solr. What magento version do you use? Do you have extensions which extends catalog functionality?"

Comment: Please do not post such answers. It is more a like comment.